# error when trying upload yii2 project to a server

Tags: php, html, nginx, yii2

I'm trying to upload my Yii2 project to a server. When I try to load `index.php` in the web folder, I got an error:

> `yii\base\Exception` with message 'Class `yii\base\model` not found'.

I understand that Yii2 haven't found the model, but I don't know why it happened. I can't also get in the other views. Do I need to change something else in the code?

This is Buscar `model` contents.

```
class Buscar extends model // This is line 6 that was mentioned in the error
{
    public $q, $m, $t, $p, $a;

    public function rules()
    {       
        return[
            ["q", "match", "pattern" => '/^[0-9a-záéíóúñ\s]+$/i', 'message' => 'Sólo se aceptan letras y numeros'],
            ["m", "match", "pattern" => '/^[0-9a-záéíóúñ\s]+$/i', 'message' => 'Sólo se aceptan letras y numeros'],
            ["t", "match", "pattern" => '/^[0-9a-záéíóúñ\s]+$/i', 'message' => 'Sólo se aceptan letras y numeros'],
            ["p", "match", "pattern" => '/^[0-9a-záéíóúñ\s]+$/i', 'message' => 'Sólo se aceptan letras y numeros'],
            ["a", "match", "pattern" => '/^[0-9a-záéíóúñ\s]+$/i', 'message' => 'Sólo se aceptan letras y numeros'],                             
        ];      
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'q' => "Buscar:", //esto aparece en index
            'm' => "Buscar Monografia:",
            't' => "Buscar Tesis:",
            'p' => "Buscar Publicacion Periodica:",
            'a' => "Buscar Articulos:"              
        ];      
    }

    ...
}
```

I don't know if the error is in `extends model` and should be `extends Model`?

Comment: What error does it show? Does it work on your local server? If yes, what are the differences between your local and server's environment... you need to do more effort on your own first, then when stuck with problem, please make sure you describe the details properly

Comment: the error is show in the image link. the project run perfect in the local server over apache in windows. the server environment is in unix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Use `yii\base\Model` instead of `yii\base\model`, can be a problem with case. There are huge difference between Windows and Unix, it's highly recommended to have the same environment on local and production servers.

**2)** Make sure that you installed composer packages and autoload file was created.

Comment: yes,thats what i think about the case sensitive. about the composer, im cuttin my project folder and pasted in the unix folder where it should run. i dont know if it will affect when i tryto run the project?. and yes the autoload file was created